# How to get every Value from DB if nothing is selected in DropDown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

i've got a new Problem or i'm just a little bit stuck with my Head.

I have a few DropDownLists. In there you can chose a Value or nothing. Both is important for the where clause in the LINQ Statement after chosing a Value. So what i need is, if you chose a value it should say (for example):

```
var result = from c in context.table
             where c.name == dropdown.selectedvalue
             select c.id;
```

Thats the easier part. So my problem is, if you chose the null/empty field in the dropdown it should give me every result from the DB. Like the same Statement above but without the where clause.

My biggest problem is, i have 4 different DropDownLists and every List is an Element for the where clause. My LINQ Statement is about 30 lines long and i don't want to copy the Statement 5 times for every case.

```
var finishedReports = (from r in context.response
                       from c in context.maxCTs
                       from t in context.ticket
                       join tp in context.priorities
                           on t.ticket_priority_id equals tp.id
                       join ts in context.states
                           on t.ticket_state_id equals ts.id
                       from a in context.article
                       where (from ti in context.ticket
                              where ti.tn == r.tn
                              select new { ti.id }).Contains(new { id = a.ticket_id })
                       where r.change_time >= startdat &&
                           r.change_time <= enddat &&
                           r.tn == c.tn &&
                           t.tn == r.tn
                       //where t.queue_id == queueID &&
                       //    tp.id == priority &&
                       //    ts.name.Contains(status)
                       orderby r.tn
                       select new
                       {
                           r.tn,
                           r.title,
                           a.id,
                           a.a_subject,
                           a.article_type_id,
                           a.a_from,
                           tp.id,
                           ts.name,
                           r.change_time,
                           r.start_date,
                           r.create_date,
                           c.finish_date
                       }).Distinct();
```

How do i write in the Statement that it should take every Data from DB when the chosen Value from the DropDownList is null or empty? 
(the commented line in the code above is the where clause with comparing the values from the dropdownlists)

Thanks for every help and if my Question is to Confusing i'll change it!

Answer (score 1):

Have a lambda like this, only SQL will then be generated if the dropdown has a value

```
where dropdown.value == "" || db.myfield == dropdown.value
```

Comment: but it should also be generated when nothing (= everything) is selected in the dropdownlist. I also can add an item to the list which says "all" but then i have to write in the statement - `if (selectedvalue == all) take every data from DB` - but there's no possibilty to write an if into a where clause (?!). I'd have to change the hole linq query and that's what i don't want to do (i think there's an easier way?!)

Comment: Correct! The way to write an "If" in a lambda is to use || and &&

Comment: no not really - || and && are completely different to If(case) then else?!?!
and i don't understand the meaning of your `where dropdown.value == ""` - i need it like `if(dropdown.value == null) { do NOT add clause to where statement } else if(dropdown.value == 1) { add a special clause to where statement }` etc. etc.

Comment: ok, with boolean logic it would look like ((dropdown.value == 1) && (add special clause)) || (dropdown.value == 2) && (some other special case)), there is no need to specify the null case, just specify everything that actually needs to generate something in the where.

Comment: so you mean that i should add EVERY CASE to the where clause? That would be a hilarious long where clause. And at the end it depends on the logged in user how many cases from the CheckBoxList i have.

I just think that my Question is wrong. I'll overwork it and maybe then it's easier to understand what i need.